# The title bar is still on screen after the jQuery dialogbox closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I used jQuery dialog box to load another webpage. I have a problem after closing the dialog box. After the dialog box is closed, the title bar is still on the screen. I want it to be completely gone. The dialog box is load on div and opened successfully. Would someone tell me how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Screenshot after the dialog box is closed.

[image: After close, the title bar still on screen]

There is my parent page code:

```
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test1.aspx.vb"      Inherits="Test.Test1" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
  <script src="include/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script  language="javascript" src="/include/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="/include/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="/include/dailog1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnOrder').click(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             openBox('Test2.aspx?orderid=0', 'Testing', 700, 650);

        });
    });

</script>
<title>Parent page</title>
 </head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnOrder" runat="server" Text="Order" />
     <div id="dialog-box"/>
   </div>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is child page code:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test.Test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Include/scripts.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="/include/dailog1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Include/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script language="javascript" src="/include/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script language="javascript" src="/include/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <base target="_self" />
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCancel').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            CloseDialogBox();

        });
 });
     </script>
  <title>Dialog Box</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save" />
     </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There is my code to open the dialog box:

```
function openDailogBox(url, name, width, height) {  
    $('#dialog-box').load(url).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        height: height
        width: width,       
        title: name,
        modal: true,
       draggable: false

    });
  $('#dialog-box').dialog('open');
  return false;
 }
```

The Close button is on the webpage which is inside the dialog box:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCancel').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            CloseDialogBox();

        });
    });
```

Here is the code to close the dialog box. (If I don't include the code to attach the dialog, I get a JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close')

```
function CloseDialogBox() {   

    $('#dialog-box').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,     
    title: name,
    modal: true,
});

$('#dialog-box').dialog('close');   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I comment the below jQuery files on Test2.aspx then it work.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Include/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script language="javascript" src="/include/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="/include/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether the dialog widget has been attached to an element before trying to use it.

```
function CloseDialogBox() {
    if ($"#dialog-box").is(":ui-dialog")) {
        $("#dialog-box").dialog("close");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but it didn't work. When the button is click, The RequiredFieldValidator show the warning on the page and it didn't run the function.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Bamar, I think you want me to make my project on jsFiddle. I have never used it. I think I need to create an account. I need to show another page. How can I do it?

Comment: You don't have to create an account to use jsfiddle. You can also make the example here using [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to add my code on the Stack Snippets, but it didn't run. I don't know how to do it

Comment: The do it using jsfiddle. Select jQuery UI 1.9.1 and there will be a checkbox to load jQuery UI.

Comment: Without seeing your full code, I don't know how to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I tried the jsifiddle but I have two pages. How can I put in on the same html section?

Comment: The child page should just be the contents of the DIV that gets loaded into the dialogue, it shouldn't be an entire HTML page. It shouldn't reload jQuery and jQuery-UI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98280/discussion-between-user819774-and-barmar).